# AVAudioSourceNode how to set set format

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

I am using the new AVAudioSourceNode to provide a stream of samples to be played through my audio interface.

However I have discovered that the AVAudioSourceNode is choosing it's own format settings.

```
engine.connect(srcNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: stimulusFormat)
```

I use the above line of code to connect my source node to my main mixer using the format 'stimulusFormat'
I have set this format using:

```
let stimulusFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32,
        sampleRate: Double(sampleRate),
        channels: 1,
        interleaved: format.isInterleaved)
```

(with the interleaved paramter querying what the output would expect to see). However whenever I query the format of my srcNode (AVAudioSourceNode), the console returns

```
<AVAudioFormat 0x600002131810:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter>
```

so clearly the stream format is not set in the connect line of code.  I have also tried changing the preferred Sample Rate, however this still does not change the AVSourceNode samplerate.  Everything else in my audio engine runs at 48000Hz, so I am not sure where it is getting this number from.

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredSampleRate(Double(sampleRate))
```

Can anyone suggest a way to define the stream format?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
engine.connect(srcNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: srcNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
```

Comment: If the sourceNode does not have a specified Format, and you try to connect it with reference to it's own format, then wont it use the format of the engines output as default format?  So in this instance if the samples for the sourceNode were pre generated then at the wrong sampleRate these samples would be read faster or slower producing different pitches. I am not discovering more issues at play to do with AVFoundation formats not producing correct results and have reported it to them

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which stumped me for days.  My solution:

Be careful when initializing the source node.  The "signal generator" example from Apple uses the first initializer of AVAudioSourceNode:

```
init(renderBlock: AVAudioSourceNodeRenderBlock)
```

But you should should use the second initializer, which explicitly sets the format.

```
init(format: AVAudioFormat, renderBlock: AVAudioSourceNodeRenderBlock)
```

It does not seem to be sufficient to just set the format in the call to "connect".